# How can I prove that

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let we have the following ultrametric space $(z,|.|_2)$ such that if $x=r.2^n$ then $|x|_2=2^{-n}$ how can I prove that the topology produced by this metric isn't discrete topology ?

Comment: What is the set $z$? What kind of a thing is $r$? More context is needed.

Comment: @CameronBuie t he set of integer numbers ${..,-2,-1,0,1,2,....}$

Comment: What kind of a thing is $r$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try being more precise. You are defining an ultrametric $d$ on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers by setting
$$
|x|_2=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=0$}\\[3px]
2^{-n} & \text{if $x\ne0$ and $x=2^nr$, with $r$ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
and $d(x,y)=|x-y|_2$.

Now consider the sequence $(2^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Is it convergent?

Comment: Yes I think it converges to zero

Comment: @Mhmdataturk And in a discrete space, the only convergent sequences are…

Answer (score -1):

Show that there is some $y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\{y\}$ is not open. For a hint, hover over the spoiler box below:

> Note that $|x-0|_2=|x|_2$ for any $x\in\Bbb Z.$

Comment: What have you written ?

Comment: In the spoiler box? Hover your cursor over it or click on it to see it.